# Apache showing error while starting in xampp

Tags: apache, xampp, localhost

I have installed `xampp` server recently of the version 7.3.1 . When I tried to start the `mysql` and `apache`. The sql server started properly but Apache didn't start and it showed the below error

```
11:05:42 AM  [Apache]   Problem detected!
11:05:42 AM  [Apache]   Port 80 in use by "Unable to open process" with PID 4!
11:05:42 AM  [Apache]   Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
11:05:42 AM  [Apache]   You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
11:05:42 AM  [Apache]   or reconfigure Apache and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
11:05:42 AM  [Apache]   Attempting to start Apache app...
11:05:42 AM  [Apache]   Status change detected: running
11:05:48 AM  [Apache]   Status change detected: stopped
11:05:48 AM  [Apache]   Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
11:05:48 AM  [Apache]   This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
11:05:48 AM  [Apache]   improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
11:05:48 AM  [Apache]   Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
11:05:48 AM  [Apache]   the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
11:05:48 AM  [Apache]   If you need more help, copy and post this
11:05:48 AM  [Apache]   entire log window on the forums
```

Then later I googled it and found that we need to change the port number 80 to any number. So I made the changes from 80 to 81 and restarted the server again it is showing the same error.

I made port changes as below

```
#Listen 12.34.56.78:81 #changed 80 to 81
Listen 81 #changed 80 to 81

ServerName localhost:81 #changed 80 to 81
```

[image]
Is there any solution for this

Comment: You should try to use Devserver instead (https://www.easyphp.org). With Devserver, if a port is already used, it takes another one automatically.

Comment: Does this Devserver has the same functionality as Xampp? @PeterEstiven

Comment: Yes, and even more I think. Several modules are available.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the apache_start.bat to see if the port is actually the problem.